# ! LaTeX Error: File `filename.cls' not found

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu

While building a fresh new document `p1.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{p1}
\begin{document}
Hello this is intro page
\end{document}
```

using Texmaker installed on Ubuntu OS, following error occured.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `p1.cls' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
```

Manual compile command `pdflatex p1.tex`

What am I doing wrong / how to fix it?

Comment: If your file is called `p1.tex`, then you probably still need to pick a document class `.cls` file like `article.cls` by using `\documentclass{article}`.

Comment: ohh great thanks a lot.. since new to latex wasnt aware of arguments to document class

Comment: The class (`.cls`) and the style files `.sty` is where most of the mainstream stuff is loaded; your personal refinements go in the preamble. And as a general policy, don't name your article `article.tex` when you're going to be using `article.cls` and/or `article.sty`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Why is this question still closed? I edited the question trying to shed light into it. I also would like to answer: Document Class is defined as p1 which apparently does not exist. Choose a valid document class e.g. articel: \documentclass{article}